# Converting a full date string like "Saturday 23rd March 2019" to Javascript Date()

Tags: javascript, date, data-conversion

How can I convert a string like "Saturday 23rd March 2019" to Javascript date?

For some reason it says invalid date and other questions similar to this are trying to convert strings like "23-03-2019 10:00" etc to Date, whereas this is more of a full date string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's actually the "rd" of 23rd that's causing the issue.  Otherwise the string as is will convert to a date.  I've used a regex replace to substitute "23rd" with "23".  Also tossed in another example to capture "1st" as well.

```js
var dateString = "Saturday 23rd March 2019";

var cleanDateString = dateString.replace(/(\d+)(rd|st|nd|th)/, "$1");

console.log(new Date(cleanDateString));

dateString = "Friday 1st March 2019";

cleanDateString = dateString.replace(/(\d+)(rd|st|nd|th)/, "$1");

console.log(new Date(cleanDateString));
```

Comment: If you're going to the trouble of modifying the string to give it to a parser, you might as well just parse it yourself, it's just 3 lines of code. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Best bet would be use a library like [moment js](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) to parse that string and tell it the format expected :

```js
const str = "Saturday 23rd March 2019";
const m = moment(str, "dddd Do MMMM YYYY");

console.log(m.toDate())
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

If the formatting is not consistent you will need to write a custom parser which won't be a trivial exercise.

Comment: "*If the formatting is not consistent…*" then any parser will struggle, as evidenced by the vagaries of built–in parsers. ;-)